# How to create temp queue in Spring Websocket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, stomp, spring-websocket

While using Spring full-featured message broker using STOMP, it creates a queue for each new session, and by default the queue is durable. Is there a way to make queues per session non-durable(auto-delete).

I have tried adding headers like `{'durable': false,'auto-delete': true}` in `SUBSCRIBE` frame and, spring gives an error of `MessageBroker not Active`.